# Rgnuplot - passing variable to gp.cmd

Tags: r, gnuplot

I need to plot graphics with Rgnuplot from a variable.

I'm trying

```
h <- gp.init()

gp.cmd(h, "plot 'fx'");
```

with `fx` is defined variable in R environment, but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 with R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy".

`fx` is a 2D matrix data.

Comment: Write R version and error please

Comment: What about using `gp.plot.x` or `gp.plot.equation`?

Comment: I've edit the question. Currently, I'm using `gp.splot(fx, type = 'map')` and it's work.

Comment: `gp.splot` is for 3D plots, which in your case is projected as a 2D map. So why don't you try the 2D-version, which could be `gp.plot`? With your `gp.cmd` you just pass a string to gnuplot without any data.